# Is it possible to modify the chrome download directory during the test execution?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here, it is possible to set the default download directory using preferences in chrome_capability during the driver initialization.

But, is it possible to modify the chrome preferences during the test?

In my scenario, I need to download a particular file in a specific directory, in order to access the file(since the filename is randomly generated) so that i can keep the 'specific directory' clean and get the file name(since there will be only one file)

Comment: Why not clear that folder before test, or sort by latest date ???

Comment: tests are running in parallel and sharing the same download path, clearing the folder is not an option here, thats why i came up here.

Comment: Maybe You can create folder in downladed folder and then store it in that folder ???

Comment: @SkorpEN inorder to store that particular file in a directory, i need to have the file name, and if i have the file name, i wouldn't have asked this question.

Comment: Question is: "Is it possible to modify the chrome download directory during the test execution?" so it is directly releted to directory. not to the file.

Comment: Of course not, I have specified  modify the download directory, i.e when i click a download link the file should go automatically into that directory, not a copy paste thing in here, i afraid you haven't got the question right.. And looking at your previous comment on "create folder in downladed folder and then store it in that folder"  i hope you still not getting it..

Comment: My idea is like that. Empty download directory before test(or backup it somewhere else). After download in folder should be only one folder. Then you got your file. Then you could return all files as their were.

Answer (score 1):

I searched a bit and lots of people said that Driver options have to be declared before driver initialization so it is not possible to change download directory after you initialized driver object. You need to open new driver and set its options while your test in execution.